# Javascript - trigger custom parent html event from child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I am trying to trigger a custom event in a parent element from the child elements event.  The parent element is HelpMenuHeader and it's custom event is defined in HTML as "onsubmenu_click".

Here's a snippet of the HTML that just shows one menu tree.

```
<span class="formMenu" id="HelpMenuHeader" onsubmenu_click="OnMenuClick()">Help
    <div class="formMenu" id="HelpAbout" onmouseup="MenuChildClick()">About us...</div>
</span>
```

In the child element, HelpAbout, the MenuChildClick event needs to trigger the parent's onsubmenu_click event so that that will execute (that event handler uses the parent's information).

Here's a snippet of the javascript I have for MenuChildClick:

```
function MenuChildClick()
{
    var srcElement = this.event.srcElement;
    if (srcElement.id != "spacer" && srcElement.tagName != "HR")
    {
        // NONE OF THE LINES BELOW WORK
        //parent.$(srcElement).trigger('onsubmenu_click');
        //$(srcElement).trigger('onsubmenu_click');
        //var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        //event.initEvent('submenu_click', true, true, null);
        //srcElement.dispatchEvent(event);
        //oEvent = createEventObject();
        //oEvent.result = srcElement.id;
        //onsubmenu_click.fire(oEvent);
    }
}
```

1. I'm having a problem getting a reference to the correct parent element in the MenuChildClick event because when I check the parent reference doesn't have the parent ID.
2. And then once I have the correct parent reference I need to execute the parent's onsubmenu_click custom event.  (The parent event is already being listened to since it's defined in the HTML, right?)

I have to support IE compatibility view so I need it to work for previous IE versions as well.

Anyone tell me how I can do these things (1 & 2 above) leaving the HTML as it is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can't you just call `OnMenuClick()` from within `MenuChildClick()`? Also, you're not defining the `parent` element (you're looking for `$(srcElement).parent()`), and you're overriding the `event` JavaScript keyword.

Comment: Why don't you call the event directly on `MenuChildClick()` ?

Comment: How do I call the parent's event?
I can't call OnMenuClick() directly because it needs a reference to the parent because it uses the "event" object to do a lot of stuff on the parent.

Comment: Why are you using events on the parent? Can't you just use `$(this)`? That would likely resolve your issue, and allow you to call `OnMenuClick()` from within `MenuChildClick()`. Could you please update your question to include the code for `OnMenuClick()` as well? :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to pass the element that is triggering the event in your HTML by changing your HTML to this:

```
<span class="formMenu" id="HelpMenuHeader" onsubmenu_click="OnMenuClick()">Help
    <div class="formMenu" id="HelpAbout" onmouseup="MenuChildClick(this); return false;">About us...</div>
</span>
```

Notice that I pass the element that is triggering the function call by passing 'this' through the onmouseup function call.

Then you can use the passed element to define which elements you want to monitor as follows:

```
function MenuChildClick(element)
{
    var srcElement = element;
    var parent = element.parentNode
    if (srcElement.id != "spacer" && srcElement.tagName != "HR")
    {
        //parent.trigger('onsubmenu_click');
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried a few of these suggestions and the event isn't triggering.  So I did a simple test:
                                                             
    var parent = $(document.getElementById('HelpAbout')).parent();
    parent.trigger('onsubmenu_click');
                                                                                                  
The parent reference is on the right element but the event is still not triggered.  I don't get it.  This should work.  Could it be due to the event being defined in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery methods `.on()` and `.trigger()` instead of event handler attribute

```js
$(function() {
   function parentHandler(event, args) {
     console.log(event.type, args)
   }
  $("#HelpMenuHeader").on("submenu_click", parentHandler);
  $("#HelpAbout").on("mouseup", function() {
    $(this).parent().trigger("submenu_click"
    , ["triggered from #" + this.id])
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span class="formMenu" id="HelpMenuHeader">Help
    <div class="formMenu" id="HelpAbout">About us...</div>
</span>
```

Comment: I tried this but when I run it the code is not going into the functions, i.e. onmouseup isn't going into the function when I click on HelpAbout.

Comment: What do you mean by "isn't going into the function when I click on HelpAbout"?

Comment: I'm running it in debug mode and have breakpoints in the functions and when I click on HelpAbout it doesn't go into the function.  I have to run in IE compatibility view so I wonder if that is stopping it.